# Time to full improvement after single workout with strength training

Tags: recovery, muscle-recovery

I'm a 29 y/o male starting strength training for the first time. I've done cardio my whole life and there were 3 rules of thumb I had in terms of time expectations:

1. It takes about 4 months after starting cardio until significant fitness gains are noticable.
2. It takes about 24 hours after a single cardio session until there has been enough recovery to train again ("time to recovery")
3. It takes about 10 days after any given cardio session until the body recovers *and becomes stronger* ("time to *improvement*)

Now number (1) and (2) I have an understanding of for strength training (1 is still about 4 months and 2 is now 48-72 hours). But number 3 I have no idea.

Of course, there is far too much 'noise' between individual sessions to be able to notice an improvement from a single workout. However, metric 3 is still very useful. I know, for example, that if I train cardio less than 10 days before a race, I will be able to recover, but I won't see all of the benefits from that training. So with <10 days to go before I race I only do moderate excercise. Metric 3 also allows me to set realistic expectations after a very intense session about when I might see benefits from it.

I have found a lot of information available about how long after strength training you have to wait until you can do strength training again. But I can't find information about how long it takes after a strength session until you have recovered *and* accrued all the benefits of that session.

I am aware that for beginners you might actually break down more muscle than you can rebuild afterwards for the first few weeks. I've been going for 3 months now though so should be through that soon.

Comment: "I have found a lot of information available about how long after strength training you have to wait until you can do strength training again" I would be interested to know where, because there are many different ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#3 works differently for muscle groups than it does the heart. The hypertrophy/strength process involves increasing fluid in muscles or increasing muscle fibers through a complex process. I'd argue that this is accomplished in a single workout due to

1. the longer you go without training a muscle, even a single workout, it can interrupt training and possibly even weaken you if you miss more than a couple week's worth of effort training a muscle.
2. Muscle fibers can grow after each workout.

So to answer the question, I would say 48 hours(after recovery). You can try to deload and recover the nervous system and the body as a whole for about 9-14 days. If you were a strength competitor, sometimes they train up to an event, having just enough time to recover. There's workouts I've done where I increase either a small amount of reps or weight each week. I remember training three times a week with the same exercises for each muscle(not recommended for best growth but I'm trying to make a point). Each training session when I did a dumbbell bench press, I was stronger than I was two days ago, either better managed my workout without fatiguing, or increasing reps or weight, even if it was 1 rep.